# Django rest framework custom Response middleware

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I use Django Rest Framework with rest_auth (/login, /logout/, /register...)
I have a Middleware, normally triggered by user_logged_in or user_logged_out signals.

In my Middleware, I want to use Response object from Rest framework.

My middleware.py

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class OneSessionPerUserMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):

        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.session_key != Session.objects.filter(session_key__in = request.user.session_key):
                logout(request)
                return Response(request)
        return self.get_response(request)
```

I suppose that I pass my condition,  but I get this error :

```
 The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed
```

How to use correctly the API Response object in a middleware ?
And I don't understand really what is : self.get_response = get_response ?

Comment: just remove your `return Response(request)`. Let your views process the request with `return self.get_response(request)`. You should handle the logged out case gracefully anyway.

Comment: So I can't use the default API display to add some custom message "already logged" , for example ?

Comment: if you really want to handle this for all requests in your middleware, regardless of the api view being called, then see the answer given by Nafees.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`return Response(request)` is not something django can handle. Ps you are passing request object to `Response` what does that mean?

Actually `Request` and `Response` classes from rest framework are not compatible with django. rest framework wraps `WSGIRequest` (django's builtin) with `Request` object in `APIView` and after getting `Response` object from view, it creates `HttpResponse` object by unwrapping it. So `Response` object can only be used in rest framework views. You can use `JsonResponse` from `django.http` in middleware like this

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.user.session_key != Session.objects.filter(session_key__in = request.user.session_key):
        logout(request)
        return JsonResponse({'logout': True}) # or whatever data you want to return 
return self.get_response(request)
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all: if you are using something other than `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` as an authentication_class, then `request.user` is set outside of middlewares (somewhere during `View.dispatch`)

If you are sure that request.user is always corresponding to `request.user` inside rest_framework views and just want to return a response:

A. Look at the [`APIView.finalize_response`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.3/rest_framework/views.py#L415): it's relatively "complex" because it can use different renderers (depending on accept-content request header), it may change headers. If you can access instance of your view in the middleware, then you can call `view.finalize_response(request, response)`, if you don't have it then you can try doing `rest_framework.views.APIView().finalize_response(...)`

B. You can use [`django.http.HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects): manually generate string for body, and specify appropriate `content_type`. And `django.http.JsonResponse` may be handy too.

C. I assumed that instead of `return Response(request)` you really are doing something else (like `Response(data=...)`). If you just need to return results from view, then remove `return Response(request)`, so that `return self.get_response(request)` kicks in. But you are making a logout, so maybe you should return some instance of [`django.http.HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)