# Django REST: How to return 500 error from custom middleware instead of the KeyError: '...' if a cookie is missing in request?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I have a custom middleware where I check whether incoming requests have a cookie present or not. If the cookie is not present, then it shows `KeyError:`.

```
[15/May/2021 18:00:05] "GET /api/auth/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 62653
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\<dir>\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\<dirs\to\middleware>\middleware.py", line 49, in __call__
    myCookie = request.COOKIES['my_cookie']
KeyError: 'my_cookie'
```

I want it to return only a `500 Internal Server Error` if the cookie is not present. How do I do this?

This is my middleware:

```
class AuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path == '/api/auth/profile/':

            try:
                myCookie = request.COOKIES['my_cookie']
                // do something with the cookie
                return self.get_response(request)

            except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
                // do something
                return self.get_response(request)
```

Here, I only check whether the token has expired but I couldn't add mechanism to handle a `KeyError`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add another exception like this:

```
try:
    myCookie = request.COOKIES['my_cookie']
    // do something with the cookie
    return self.get_response(request)

except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
    // do something
    return self.get_response(request)

except KeyError:
    // do something
    return self.get_response(request)
```

Or you can use

```
my_cookie = request.COOKIES.get('my_cookie', None)
if not my_cookie:  # cookie not found
   # do something
return self.get_response(request)
```

Comment: Here, if I return `self.get_response(request)` from `except KeyError`, it'll be an unauthorized access. So I want to return a 500 error from this response. Now, can I return errors or statuses from custom middlewares?

Comment: It is possible. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52827952/2696165

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround with `HttpResponseServerError`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError

class AuthMiddleware:
    ...
    def __call__(self, request):
        ...
        except KeyError:
            response = HttpResponseServerError()
            response.write("<h2>Error: Cookie [ access ] is missing!</h2>")
            return response
```

I think it's better to use [DRF custom exceptions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/) for this issue.